# What does くんな mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

A: 嬢ちゃん、茶ぁおかわりくんな！

B: はい、少々お待ちください！

It's probably an informal way to say "please" or something based on the context, but I can't find anything to confirm that. Only that くんな can be a shorter and more masculine way to say 来るな, but I don't see how that makes sense here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「くんな」 here means "***gimme ~~, won't ya?***".  It is tough guy speech and you would not hear it very often in real life (unless you are surrounded by tough guys. that is.)  You would see/hear it more often in fiction.

> "Girl, gimme another cup of tea, will you?"
>
> "Sure, just a sec!"

「くんない」 will be heard considerably more often than 「くんな」 both in real life and fiction.

Both phrases should come from 「くれない」= "Can you give me ~~?"

This 「くんな」 has absolutely nothing to do with 「来{く}んな」("Don't come!").  Those are even pronounced differently.

「くんな{HHH}」 vs. 「来んな{HLL}」

Comment: Mind clarifying the pronunciation portion at the end? I'm not sure how the representation given translates phonetically.